# GlusterFS with RAID-1

Tags: linux, raid, distributed-filesystems

Is it possible to use GlusterFS to have more flexible FS and to support higher capacity + RAID-1 to have redundancy to avoid data loss in case of failure?

I need to get a mirrored FS that has high flexibility in scaling (adding more HDs and/or adding more machines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.gluster.com/products/features.php

Answer (score 1):

Well yes you can expand your file system and yes the disks you use to build it can be mirrored, so yes to both questions.